# vue.js: How can I create a dynamic key in v-for when key is a date?

Tags: vue.js

I am struggling to figure out how to create a `:key` value for my `v-for` loop & I believe that is why the order of my list(s) are random.

This is what my template looks like:

```
<div v-for="(items, index) in documents">
    <h1>{{ index }}</h1> // 2020-06-02
    ...

    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td> // Foo
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My `documents` prop looks like this:

```
{
    2020-06-01: ['name': 'Foo', ...],
    2020-06-02: ['name': 'Bar', ...],
    2020-06-03: ['name': 'Baz', ...],
}
```

My props are returning the `documents` in the correct order, but they are not shown on screen in the correct order. For example, I'll see `2020-06-03, 2020-06-01, 2020-06-02` or a different combination. I think it's because I don't have a `:key` so Vue doesn't know how to order things.

Since I am using the `index` in my outter loops, I'm not sure how to get a unique key.

What I think I need is something like:

```
<div v-for="(items, date, index) in documents" :key="index">...</div>
```

But, that's not really how it works.

I've also tried something like:

```
<div v-for="(items, index) in documents" :key="`i-${index}`">...</div>
```

No luck there either.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Thank you for your feedback! Here's a few notes.

I'm getting `documents` from another source. I'm passing it is as props to my component. Currently, I'm using a computed property to *try* to alter the actual object; maybe add a key or something. No luck just yet...

Just as you've stated, it is coming in as an object. Each key of the object is a date. Each date, then has an array that I'm also looping through.

Here is what `documents` looks like (also added a screenshot). You can see that the dates are in order. The props are straight from my external service, so things look great so far.

```
{
    2020-06-01: ['name': 'Foo', ...],
    2020-06-02: ['name': 'Bar', ...],
    2020-06-03: ['name': 'Baz', ...],
}
```

[[image: screenshot][1]]

> you can go with index2 or whatever else you would like

I tried making `index` be `date` just to help keep things straight and yeah.. I tried adding a third argument in the `v-for` just in case there was an unknown secret I could tap into (sadly no) :)

> the format of your prop is messing me up mostly.

Same here, I'm just not able to understand why the order looks good in my props, but when looping through things, its pretty random.

> show what you want the table to look like

This is the result I'm trying to accomplish.

```
<h2>2020-06-01</h2>. // this is the "missing" index (outer loop)
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
</tr>
<tr> // this is the array that exists within each date
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>foo@example.com</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Edit/Solution**

Thank you *so* much @Goofballtech! Your answer really helped me think about what I had and directions to try. Here's what I ended up with. `sortedDocuments` is a computed property; `this.documents` is a reference to the `documents` props that is getting passed in.

```
sortedDocuments() {
    const data = this.documents;

    return Object.keys(data)
        .map((date) => {
            return {
                date: date,
                data: data[date],
            }
        })
        .sort(function (a, b) {
            let dateA = new Date(a.date);
            let dateB = new Date(b.date);

            return dateA - dateB;
        })
        .reverse();
    },
```

Comment: What does you document array look like? Can you please edit the question?

Comment: screen shot didn't work that i can see, edit-n/m. i see the url now. i was looking at the embeded link that wasn't showing an image. Can you expand one of the array to see it's contents int he image?

Comment: i cannot seem to make a key/value array be valid JSON. If complains that there shouldn't be a colon in the array. It want a comma or ] to end the array. 
{
   "2020-06-01":[
      "name":      "Foo"
   ],
   "2020-06-02":[
      "name":      "Bar"
   ],
   "2020-06-03":[
      "name":      "Baz"
   ]
}

Comment: did you get it figured out?

Comment: Just did!! Thank you so much for your answer. The detail really helped me figure it out. I've updated my question with what worked - if you can edit your answer to include it maybe it'll help someone else. Thank you again!!!

Comment: just curious, what did your function do that wasnt already there? (other than .reverse()) of coarse... or was it just to pull it all into a single function you wanted?

Comment: oooo, and how was the key\value array thing structured?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:key is used to watch for changes, not necessarily for order.

2 things.

1. if you want to maintain a specific order the general solution is to use an array. Order of object (although there is a bit of method to the madness) cannot necessarily be counted upon.
2. I believe you should used a computed property to modify these as you require then iterate over that array instead of using the object directly for what it seems you are trying to do. Will be back will an edit adding code in a moment.

Edit1 -

General information about indexes in v-for. The word index is not some magic keyword. If you have nested v-for you can do this:

```
<div v-for="(stuff, index) in stuffing">
display stuff here, index is your key
  <div v-for="otherStuff, skdjdfhfyjsksj) in theOtherThings">
    skdjdfhfyjsksj is your key value here
  </div>
</div>
```

index is shown in examples to be clear but you can go with index2 or whatever else you would like there. It's getting passed as the second argument and that's where the magic happens.

Back to the base issue...So the format of your prop is messing me up mostly. Sorting the existing entries is straight forward but there really isn't a key:value array in javascript. Those are objects. So where are you getting the documents prop from originally? Is that something you are creating to pass down or is it coming that way from an external source?

sorting of the dates can be done like this in computed, this doesn't include the rest of the data yet as I'm not sure if you need to convert those on the fly or if we can change the prop before it gets here. I changed your document arrays to objects because the code would never show anything with that data formatted as an array as it complained about a missing ] since it did not expect the array key:value formatting.

https://jsfiddle.net/goofballtech/hmr6uw2a/65/

```
computed: {
    sortedDates(){
     return Object.keys(this.documents)
     .sort((a,b) => a > b ? 1 : 0)
    }
  },
```

Final request for this edit, can you show what you want the table to look like? Having that context would help in finding the optimal data structure to achieve the results you need.

Edit2 - 
Assuming the object can be an array of objects, and there is potential to have more than one name/email per date array. The below would work.

It all hinges on those funky arrays though.

Might be easier for you to copy the raw return from the API and just go in in to sterilize the data so i can see how the arrays are formatted.

https://jsfiddle.net/goofballtech/hmr6uw2a/141/

```
<div v-for="(docDate, index) in sortedDates" :key="index">
  <h3>
  {{docDate.date}}
  </h3>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(item, index2) in docDate.data.length" :key="index2">
          <td>{{documents[docDate.date][index2].name}}</td>
          <td>{{documents[docDate.date][index2].email}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response! I've updated my question to help clarify things. The initial object is throwing me off as well.